# Add Authentication to Azure Cordova app using Google

Tags: cordova, azure, authentication

I'm following the tutorial '[Add authentication to your Apache Cordova app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-users/)' but its not working me.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015, .NET backend (C#) and Google for authentication. The only changes I've made to the Azure generated code have been part of this tutorial and the code worked prior to this tutorial.

After completing the tutorial and running in the Ripple - Nexus (Galaxy) emulator it hangs when trying to authenticate. A blank browser window opens with the following url:

https://geowatch.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google/callback?state=nonce%3D2809fd403ad14683a3bdec9f1cf4189b_20160323172239%26redir%3D&code=4/5Ahd7kjtq3_PhrQBhlx6sdk1-vbDQMS47JRP344ykzs&authuser=0&session_state=d70e20097f91dcf4b08bd2418a38ba8afacce48f..d5f5&prompt=none#

When I use the Google Android Emulator the Google login screen displays (much slower than Ripple). When I login I get the following error: 
Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/wwww/index.html).

Any help is appreciated.
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow the instructions in the HOWTO for Apache Cordova on setting up external redirect URIs.  The HOWTO is here:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-how-to-use-client-library/#auth